# how to define static properties using self in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to define static properties using self.

```
class B {
    parent: B;
    constructor() {
        if (A.parent != null) {
            this.parent = A.parent;
        }
        else {
            this.parent = null;
        }
    }
}

class A {
    public static parent: B = new B();
    public static child: B = new B();
}

var hoge = new A();
```

In the above example, I'm trying to define classes A and B.
This code is translated to the below.

```
var B = (function () {
    function B() {
        if (A.parent != null) {
            this.parent = A.parent;
        } else {
            this.parent = null;
        }
    }
    return B;
})();

var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    A.parent = new B();
    A.child = new B();
    return A;
})();

var hoge = new A();
```

This code cannot be executed because A is undefined in B's constructor.

How do I define class A having static properties whose definition is using A self (such as class B)?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `A` from outside its own initializer until it is fully initialized.
Therefore, you can't create a `new B()` inside `A`'s static initializers.

Instead, set the properties outside the class:

```
class A {
    public static parent: B;
    public static child: B;
}
// A is now fully initialized and visible to the world.
A.parent = new B();
A.child = new B();
```