# Typescript call property without instance and function from instance at the same time

Tags: typescript, instance

Is possible to call the property of something (class/module/interface...) without creating instance? But also to access the function from instance of the same object name? 
I'm building my own .d.ts from API...

e.g.:

```
declare class document {
    flag;
    getFlag();
}
```

Now I need to call it like this:

```
var d = new document;
d.getFlag();
```

Which is OK, but I also need to call

```
document.flag
```

-directly, without instance. With the same name "document" in this case.

Is it possible somehow in typescript?

Comment: Why do you need that? It looks like a smell in your design. Normally you define methods as static or not depending on what you need them for, but if you need a method to be both static and non-static at a time it is probably a bad design issue

Comment: I know it is wrong, but in one of my external framework it has to be possible to use name of class as constant and call its property.

Comment: you have to set getFlag() as static ´static getFlag()´ and then you can use it as a static method, but then you cannot use it as non-static anymore. A hack could be to duplicate the method: one copy static and other copy non-static. This is a very very bad thing though. There is no other possibility. You actually need to choose between static and non-static

Comment: Simply declare them *static*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246736/how-to-define-static-properties-using-self-in-typescript

Comment: @iberbeu Thank you million times! Duplicate names helped in that rare situation and it works!

Answer (score 2):

> Which is OK, but I also need to call

You need a `static` member on the class:

```
declare class document {
    static flag;
    getFlag();
}
document.flag;
```